# How to get the AutoGenerated ID when using SaveChanges in ASP.Net MVC. My current method seems inefficient

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a StudentTable

```
(
    (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    NAME NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    .....
)
```

The model definition is

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("NAME")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false, ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ........
```

I need to get the Auto Generated ID in the database whenever I insert A record in the Student Table using

```
isDAL.StudentTable.Add(scTemp.StudentInfo);
isDAL.SaveChanges();
```

Here isDAL is the Data Access Layer which inherits DBContext class from Entity Framework.

Right now I am using a trigger which gets the ID and stores it in the LASTINSERTED table which is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE LASTINSERTED
(
    INT INSERTEDID
)
```

I use the following code to get it

```
intGeneratedID = isDAL.LASTINSERTED.ToList<Inserted>()[0].InsertedID;
```

Inserted is a dummy model which is defined as:

```
  public class Inserted
    {
        [Required]
        [Column("InsertedId")]
        public int InsertedID { get; set; }
    }
```

After getting the ID, the data in the table is deleted. Is there a better way? Create an extra record and the querying the table again seems inefficient.

Comment: After you have called `SaveChanges()`, just get the value using `scTemp.StudentInfo.ID`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use trigger here. Just do as shown below.

```
isDAL.StudentTable.Add(scTemp.StudentInfo);
isDAL.SaveChanges();
var yourPkId=scTemp.StudentInfo.ID;//this is your Auto generated PK Id
```

How easy it is... :D